# Is it possible to dynamically generate the <f:validateBean> tag?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, bean-validation

I am dynamically generating some Primefaces input and output components, and I need to be able to disable validation on these components in certain use cases, while still updating the model. (Like a save button).  It looks like the proper way to do that in xhtml would be to use `<f:validateBean disabled="#{myBean.someCondition}/>`

However, I cannot figure out how to create this component dynamically.  I searched through the javax.faces package and could not find any validateBean component.  I thought maybe it would be a property that I need to set on the UIInput component, but none of the methods outlined in that API seem to what I need.

Is this possible?

Edit:

As a reference, here is the component I am creating:

```
UIInput input = new InputText();
input.setId(field.getFieldKey());
input.setValueExpression("value", expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, field.getFieldValue(), String.class));
input.addClientBehavior("blur", ajaxBehavior);    
input.addValidator(new BeanValidator());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to explore these paths :

- Set immediate to true on your input.

  ```
  input.setImmediate(true);
  ```
- Extend BeanValidator with an empty validate method and pass an instance to your input.

  ```
  input.addValidator(new DummyBeanValidator());
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I cannot use immediate=true because I do need the values to be added to the model (without validation).  I also cannot use a dummy validator, because I need the proper validations to run when they submit the form, or on the blur event for entering data to a field.  What I need to be able to do is disable validation conditionally, while still updating the model.

Comment: Would this helps then?
http://www.springfuse.com/2011/12/15/skip-jsf-validation-depending-on-action.html

Check the LenientBeanValidator.doValidate, they check the request for a special parameter.  If it's there, they do validation, if not, they skip it.

Comment: Hmm...actually that is helpful.  I can extend the default bean validator and check for my parameter before calling the default validation function.  Thanks!